# Best approach: Move code from branch A to new branch B

Tags: git

My feature branch `foo` includes small bits of another upcoming feature that needs more work later `bar`

- `develop/foo`: Includes code i don't want here (committed & pushed)
- `develop/bar`: New branch, where i want the unwanted code from `foo`

A way to visualise it is to think different items are added to a list in one commit, now to contain fewer things, until `bar` is merged.

**Example commit:**

```
if (addToList) {
    list.add(lorem)
    list.add(ipsum)
    list.add(dolor) // *
}
```

- `*` Line needs to be moved to branch `bar`

Whats the best approach? I can copy file by file over to the new branch but it takes a lot of time

Comment: So you want `develop/bar` to look **exactly** like `develop/foo` looks right now? Or is it do they look different and you just want a couple of commits that are on `develop/foo` to be on `develop/bar` instead? Also: are force pushes acceptable here or are these shared branches?

Comment: Imagine you have 2 books, one is called `foo` and one is `bar` and the only difference is `foo` has one more page. I want(ed) to take that page and put it in `bar` instead. Want(ed) was because I ended up using a method that I still don't know is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you have written good commits (what you should do ;-)), you can just cherry-pick the relevant commits into your branch `bar`:

(cherry-picking will apply the changes of one or more commits to your recently checkedout branch)

```
git checkout bar # Switch to target branch

git cherry-pick <commitHash0> <commitHash1> ... # List of commits
```

Of course there could be some conflicts due cherry-picking. If this is the case, you need to solve them. Solving these conflict its very like on a normal merger or rebase.

Comment: I added some further explanation to my question. The question is about moving code, not specific commits, and what the best approach for it is!

Comment: But if you have written good commits, which means you have created one commit per logical modification of your code (atomic commit), there should be no reason to want just a part of this commit.


Yes i know, often commits are not as good as there should be ;-)

So you could create a second worktree of your repository. With this approach you could checkout 2 branches at the same time (in separate directories), copy lines frrom foo to bar and commit your changes. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Remove code on `develop/foo` and commit (no push)
2. Created new branch `develop/bar` from `develop/foo`
3. Created patch from revert commit (1)
4. Applied patch on `develop/bar`
5. Pushed `develop/foo`
6. Pushed `develop/bar`

Comment: The "create patch and apply" is just a long way around to do [a cherry-pick](https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/cherry-pick).

Comment: I'd agree if my problem was that I needed to move commits, but this question is about moving code rather than moving commits. I added some explanation to why this happened!

Comment: I don't understand that distinction. Commits contain code. You want to move code. Why not move the commits that contain the code?